# Add search for name, email and date in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I add search in a single field for name, email and created_at.

Without search my query is as:

```
@messages = Message.joins(:user).select('messages.*, users.name').order('created_at desc').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

For the search field my UI is as:

```
  <%= form_for :message, :url => track_emails_path , :html => {:method => :get} do |f| -%>
    <div class="ic-Input-group">
      <input class="ic-Input" type="text" id="user_name" name="user[search]" aria-labelledby="user_name_label" placeholder= "Search by name,email, date"/>
      <button class='Button'><%= t 'buttons.go', "Go" %></button>
    </div>
  <% end -%>
```

I am able to get the searched result in my params. e.g., If I search for sneh then my params are like: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"search"=>"sneh"}}`. But I am not getting how to apply where condition in my query for all the three fields: name, email and created_at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following.

```
query = params[:search]
@messages = Message.joins(:user).where("user.name LIKE ? OR user.email LIKE ? OR user.created_at LIKE ?" ,"%#{query}%", "%#{query}%","%#{query}%")
```